# Update a column if Date in another column has been breached?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, calculated-column, flow, json-formatting

I am trying to update a column value IF the Date presented in another column has been breached. 
I will then need to format the row the has breached this date in Red.

The columns are:

> Date Requested: Requested delivery date Formatted as a Date
>
> Outside SLA: Yes/No Toggle

Logic behind this:

> If Date Requested is today or greater, set outside SLA to Yes.
>   Highlight Row Red.
>
> If Date Requested is less than today, leave Outside SLA at its default
>   Value NO

Is this at all possible, i feel like i may be treating SharePoint too much like Excel which i know is incorrect.
Any advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add json formatting with the following code

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "=if([$Date] > @now, 'Yes', 'No')",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Date] > @now, '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}
```

[image]
Click on the down arrow of behind the column name, `column settings`>`format this column`

Comment: Many thanks, this handles the column formatting as needed. Dont think i will be able to do the changing of data in another column based on sharepoint limitations by the seems of things